# Django : Groups in production

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I create some groups for my users with admin system, when I make my project in production, do I have to recreate all my groups and reassign permissions ? Or I need to dump database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize the data you created and put it into a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) that will run after initial schema migrations. Your custom migrations reside in the same folder the generated ones do (`yourapp/migrations`).

What you put in the migration is up to you. It can be some SQL (e.g. a dump), or some code that uses [historical models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#historical-models) to create your objects.

This is a clean solution - you have everything you need for deployment in your migrations.

Comment: I think it's a great idea to create groups and assign permissions to these groups in a migration. But in which folder I have to add my data migrations ?

Comment: @AlexandrePécorilla I edited the answer. But generally, read the whole https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/ because you have to pay attention when dealing with migrations.

Comment: When you say in `yourapp/migrations` is in the root of project, or in same folder of settings.py urls.py wsgi.py ?

Comment: @AlexandrePécorilla they should be in the folder of a relevant app. If your project is `ride_sharing` and inside you have the main app also called `ride_sharing`, it will be in `ride_sharing/ride_sharing` alongside  `settings.py` and `urls.py`. If you have a separate app for user-related classes, you can put it there.

Comment: Ok, so I can create a file like this +> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485464/right-way-to-create-a-django-data-migration-that-creates-a-group (in second post)

Comment: @AlexandrePécorilla yes, for example. But if you (or someone else) find it more convenient to use the admin and make a dump you can do it too.